# Something wrong with Rails logger. DB query params are not shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, logging, activerecord

From some time I have noticed that I can't see properly database query params with special gems.

(Rails 5,Ruby 2.5.1, Postgresql 10)

Example: **rack-mini-profiler**, **rails_panel**:

```
SELECT  "items"."id" FROM "items" WHERE "item"."category_id" IN ($1,$2,$3) LIMIT $4;
```

Early it was:

```
SELECT  "items"."id" FROM "items" WHERE "item"."category_id" IN (11,12,13) LIMIT 20;
```

Controller action:

```
Item.select(:id).where(category_id: @ids).limit(per_page)
#let be @ids = [11,12,13], per_page = 20
```

The output of clear log in terminal:

```
Item Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "items"."id" FROM "items" WHERE "item"."category_id" IN ($1,$2,$3) LIMIT $4 

[["category_id", 11], ["category_id", 12],["category_id", 13], ["LIMIT", 20]]
```

I tried to rollback many steps of changes, but nothing changed.

What can i do to get back normal output for debug?

Comment: Are you sure that this is actually a logging issue and not that Rails is actually sending a parameterized query to the database instead?

Comment: I am not sure, but why earlier was all good to debug and now I don't see query params?... As I told, I tried to rollback changes, reinstall ruby, force reinstall gems. May be it is rack-mini-profiler issue. But I tried another similar gems and the same.. In other project I have rack-mini-profiler and it shows all params good

Comment: I don't think you're realizing that those are actually different SQL queries. And that the database is replacing the placeholders with the values - not rails.

Comment: Another project Rails 3. `Product.where(id: [1,2,3]) --> Products Load (2.3ms) SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" IN (1,2,3)` Why it is not sending parametrized query to db?

Comment: Because it's Rails 3?

Comment: so rack-mini-profiler couldn't show me query params for Rails 5, right?

Comment: No Rails 5 creates different queries than 3.

Comment: The params are in the array.

Comment: OK. ` very sad `